# How to pass parameters by URL in web.xml?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters, web.xml

I need to have something like this:

/{paramvalue}/url

And get the value of param value, and point the url to the servlet.

For example:

/josua/profile
/mary/messages

"/josua/" and "/mary/" is the parameter that I need to get

And then I need to map /{username}/profile to ProfileServlet.class and /{username}/messages to MessagesServlet.class

Is there any way that I could do this?

Answer (score 1):

It somewhat sounds like [Pretty URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_URL). If you are actually up to it, I suggest you to look into any of these frameworks, [PrettyFaces](http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/) (for JSF), and [Stripes](http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Home).

Beside, its not how we usually practice in Java and this might come with few disadvantages, you should be able to map your URL to a filter in your `web.xml`, [see BalusC post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547001/how-to-pass-parameters-by-url-in-web-xml/5551941#5551941). And then make use of `HttpServletRequest` method like `getRequestURI()` to continue further. Further, its good to look into `regex` and try to utilise that in order to come-up with this system, as [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) (a python web development framework) achieved it.

Comment: Thanks BalusC. I am quite out of touch, actually.

Answer (score 1):

Map a `Filter` on `/*` which does *basically* the following in `doFilter()` method.

```
String[] pathParams = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI().substring(1).split("/", 2);
String userName = pathParams[0];
String servletUrl = pathParams[1];

request.setAttribute("userName", userName);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/" + servletUrl).forward(request, response);
```

And map the `ProfileServlet` on `/profile/*` and `MessagesServlet` on `/messages/*`. In both servlets, the username should be available by `request.getAttribute("userName")`.